# Recolher as imagens da tag do instagram para o site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, instagram-api

Boa noite!
Eu gostaria de criar algo como o que podem ver na parte inferior desta página: http://www.theathletesfoot.com/

Apresenta todas as fotos que se vão pondo com a tag #taflovessneakers e eu gostaria de fazer o mesmo para o meu website

Será um trabalho muito complexo? Eu tenho algum conhecimento em webdevelopment mas não sou expert. O meu website é em Magento se ajudar em algo ou se souberem de alguma extensão já existente ou que poupe algum trabalho.

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Queria adicionar também um *widget* bastante simples como solução: [LightWidget](https://lightwidget.com/). Ele é de graça (mas só recarrega novas imagens do Instagram uma vez ao dia :)).

Por exemplo, para exibir as fotos da tag `#taflovessneakers` que você mencionou, bastaria adicionar as seguintes tags ao seu HTML:

```html
<!-- LightWidget WIDGET -->
<script src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/lightwidget.js"></script>
<iframe
src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/2f723c7e79095904a47b5f9b0b889bd1.html"
id="lightwidget_2f723c7e79"
name="lightwidget_2f723c7e79"
scrolling="no"
allowtransparency="true"
class="lightwidget-widget"
style="width: 100%; border: 0; overflow: hidden;"
>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você vai ter que ter a url do instagram que retorna um arquivo JSON de acordo com a tag que você quer, e para isso vai ter de gerar um token. Veja mais aqui https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/.

Depois de conseguir o seu token, troque o seu valor aqui:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/taflovessneakers/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Depois é só tratar o JSON.

Comment: eu usei essa URL e só me aparece as minhas fotos com a HASHTAG, como faço para pegar fotos públicas? Quero uma lista de todas as fotos do instagram com uma hashtag especifica...

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o que você precisa é acessar a API disponibilizada pelo instagram e montar um bloco para exibição das fotos. Caso você saiba manipular uma API, certamente não encontrará muitos problemas.

Segue abaixo link de algumas extensões free já disponíveis para o Magento:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/neklo-instagram-widget-v1-0-1.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/imagepicker-by-innobyte.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-in-one-social-feeds.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/websupreme-instagram-widget-1.html

Para conferir a lista completa, incluindo as extensões pagas, acesse:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=4&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=instagram&t=0&p=3